# How to specify all ports in Security group - CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have my CloudFormation script like this now:

```
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
      "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
      "FromPort" : "0",
      "ToPort" : "65535",
      "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
    }]
```

and it looks like this, which is fine:

[image]

But I am wondering how to I update the template to get this:

[image]

Notice the Ports say All. I also wonder if they are different?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The original solution I posted (and accepted by the original poster) stopped working as AWS no longer supports it. To avoid the barrage of downvotes, I deleted the answer. The alternatives are:

- Specify the ports 0 and 65535

or

Open all ports for **all** protocols not just TCP (as suggested by `thewire247` below)

```
"SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
  "IpProtocol" : "-1",
  "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems not to work (at least not anymore). I tried this and got `TCP/UDP (from) port (-1) out of range`. I had to specify `0` and `65535` explicitly :(

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to allow all protocols and all ports, then you can do the following

```
{
  "IpProtocol" : "-1"
  "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`FromPort`
Start of port range for the TCP and UDP protocols, or an ICMP type number. If you specify icmp for the IpProtocol property, you can specify -1 as a wildcard (i.e., any ICMP type number).

`ToPort`
End of port range for the TCP and UDP protocols, or an ICMP code. If you specify icmp for the IpProtocol property, you can specify -1 as a wildcard (i.e., any ICMP code).

ex.
`{ "IpProtocol" : "icmp", "FromPort" : "8", "ToPort" : "-1", "CidrIp" : "10.0.0.0/24" }`

ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html