# AWS Cloudformation: Security Group Rule to allow all egress

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am using the following egress rule in a security group definition of a `cloudformation` template

```
  SecurityGroupEgress:
  - IpProtocol: tcp
    FromPort: 0
    ToPort: 65535
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

However this does not end up in a rule that allow all outbound traffic;

What is the proper way to define an `allow-all-outbound` rule?

Comment: Already answered in this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021545/how-to-specify-all-ports-in-security-group-cloudformation

Comment: @AYA - I would like to see a new answer for this question. The other answer is not entirely correct today.

Comment: TCP is not the only protocol required to allow all egress.

Answer (score 20):

This is an old thread, but people still find it in searches...  True, there are times the default doesn't work well, such as when using cfn_nag_scan to scan the cft.

Here is what you are looking for:

```
  SecurityGroupEgress:
    - Description: Allow all outbound traffic
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 4):

I must add this info from the AWS documentation, as defining such a policy might not be necessary,

"When you create a VPC security group, Amazon EC2 creates a default egress rule that allows egress traffic on all ports and IP protocols to any location. The default rule is removed only when you specify one or more egress rules. "

here's the link,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#w2ab1c21c10d473c17

Typically, you define some specific port/protocol.